# SQL - Ordering the results of a recursive relationship

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I've got a databases table of account users. There are two types of account:-

- Administrator Account
- Standard Account

The data table has two additional columns, Account Number and Parent Account Number. Every record regardless gets assigned a new Account Number, but if an account is a Standard Account, then it gets assigned a Parent Account Number. I can tell who is an administrator by the fact that the Parent Account Number field is NULL.

I'm wanting to print a list of these users, ordered by the administrator account and then any children of that administrator, before moving onto the next administrator account. I'm expecting a list of:-

- Administrator (Account 1250, Parent NULL)

  - Standard Account (Account 1255, Parent 1250)
  - Standard Account (Account 1256, Parent 1250)
- Administrator (Account 1375, Parent NULL)

  - Standard Account (Account 1403, Parent 1375)

I've did a SQL query of:-

```
SELECT *
 FROM [LWC].[dbo].[AspNetUsers]
  ORDER BY AccountNumber, ParentAccountNumber
```

but this isn't ordering correctly, because every Account Number is different. I presume this would sort as I expected it to, if the AccountNumber was the same for multiple records but it isn't.

Can anyone suggest how I can sort this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: this simple like manager and its employee problem.just provide sample data.

Comment: I think `ORDER BY ISNULL(ParentAccountNumber, AccountNumber), ParentAccountNumber, AccountNumber` would do what you want.

Comment: @GarethD thanks, worked a treat. What does the ISNULL bit do? I've never seen that in a ORDERBY before?

Comment: @KumarHarsh sorry, I don't know how I can sensibly paste in a table of data.

Comment: you can create table variable and write down insert script

Comment: It does the same in an order by as it does in a select - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: ISNULL will take AccountNumber for  ordering if ParentAccountNumber is null

Comment: Thanks very much for everyone's help. How can I mark as an answer?

Comment: Hey @GarethD, can you post your code in an answer please? Your code is pretty slick but easy to miss/overlook since it is in a comment.

Comment: @MikeUpjohn, if GarethD does not make an answer out of his comment in a week or so, I would say go ahead and answer this yourself using the code he gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simply:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(ParentAccountNumber, AccountNumber), ParentAccountNumber, AccountNumber
```

would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a recursive relationship a [recursive cte](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) could be used , or a [hierarchyId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) type would / may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select * from 
    (SELECT *,
        case 
            when Parent is null then cast((cast(Account as nvarchar) + '0') as int)
            else cast((cast(Parent as nvarchar) + '1') as int)
        end as OrderCol
    FROM [LWC].[dbo].[AspNetUsers])
order by OrderCol
```